# Please add support for PowerShell syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

StackOverflow currently does not support syntax highlighting for PowerShell. Please add support for this in a future revision.

Comment: That question is also marked as a duplicate, but the supposed "duplicate" doesn't actually address the issue.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: I liked you to the same question, asked before; "Please add Powershell syntax highlighting". I did vote to reopen that one in the past (because additional options now exist for Stack Exchange to update their definitions from the highlighting project). But the canonical post to normally link to is what Antony linked to; Stack Overflow uses a third-party OSS project, when that project supports Powershell, so will Stack Overflow.

Comment: 2022 feature request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421016/enable-automatic-and-on-demand-syntax-highlighting-for-powershell-updated-for-h

Answer (score 3):

Based on the explanation on [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) there is already raised an [issue](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/295) including a sample on july, 10th, 2013.

<s>You seem to be able to 'star' that issue, until now 3 people have done that...</s> You can't *vote* on issues in Github so no idea how many users want this.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the information. For reference, the issue # is 295.