# Please bring a version of highlight.js which supports PowerShell onto Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

The main ["What is Syntax Highlighting and how does it work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) Meta question instructs us to open a question tagged `[feature-request]` to add syntax highlighting for a language which [is supported by the highlight.js project](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md), but it is not supported by the version of highlight.js used on Stack Exchange. PowerShell is such a language, so here's a question for it.

At a glance, this question looks a duplicate of:

- [Enable a "lang-powershell" option for Prettify on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362286/enable-a-lang-powershell-option-for-prettify-on-stack-overflow)
- [Please add support for PowerShell syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214232/please-add-support-for-powershell-syntax-highlighting)

But Stack Exchange has moved away from Prettify, which didn't support PowerShell, but highlight.js does, so it now comes down to:

> 2. Check that the language is supported by highlight.js
>
> If a language is already on the list but not used on Stack Exchange, please raise a feature request here on Meta to have it deployed on the network.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Did you see the TamperMonkey script that can load new languages on demand from the Highlight.js CDN? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354427/853855  Might be helpful for languages SO truly decides they are not going to add to improve the experience of individuals.  I'm sure it could easily be turned into a Chrome Extension or something also if anyone was interested.

Comment: *you can raise a feature request on Meta to request that a new version of highlight.js be deployed* @KonradRudolph That's definitely my plain understanding at a plain reading of the post.

Comment: I've bundled this support into a Chrome extension if that would be helpful to you: https://github.com/joshgoebel/se_highlightjs  It pretty much adds all our missing languages to SE (when they are manually hinted).  Also on the list is adding auto-hinting support - so any post tagged "powershell" would "just work".

Comment: 2022 feature request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421016/enable-automatic-and-on-demand-syntax-highlighting-for-powershell-updated-for-h

Answer (score 2):

For what it’s worth, **Stack Overflow *still* does not provide a good option for PowerShell at all** right now.

To show this, let's look at one of the most-basic items in PowerShell: the [`Get-Date`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date) cmdlet.

Starting with `<!-- language: lang-powershell -->`

```powershell
Get-Date
```

Or  ```` ```sh ````

```sh
Get-Date
```

Both cases see the `-` as a subtraction operator and then show the words "Get" and "date" in different colors. Yet clearly this is one call to the `Get-date` cmdlet.

There's also  ```` ```powershell ````

```
Get-Date
```

which does *nothing at all*, and  ```` ```lang-default ````

```
Get-Date
```

which at least allows some kind of detection to work, but it still gets it wrong.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, just a corollary.

Comment: Also, please [don't post the same content to multiple questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426816)

Comment: @zcoop98 Your addition here is based on an inaccurate assumption that it's a bug and introduces a red herring into the discussion. The version of highlight.js doesn't matter for this. The issue is that Stack Exchange *doesn't include PowerShell syntax in the languages available in the page*. Thus, all attempts to try to use PowerShell syntax highlighting *on Stack Exchange* won't pull in an actual highlighting definition. So, specifying `powershell` syntax highlighting does nothing (it might be useful, eventually, when at some point in the future SE includes the PowerShell syntax definition).

Comment: Apologies @Makyen , you're totally right. I thought that PS highlighting was included; I see now that it's not in [the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109).

Comment: It may not make a difference for the syntax highlighting in this case, but *[Get-date](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date)* is not the official spelling of the cmdlet (though it is case insensitive). For instance, for Java, it makes a difference: If the normal Java conventions are not followed (e.g., for variable names), the syntax highlighting will not be correct. Or in other words, the current syntax highlighter in some cases (or all cases?) ***expects*** the platform conventions to be followed

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum corrected